# Architecture vs. Language

Tags: api, architecture

I attended a seminar about API basics yesterday and something struck out as odd to me. We covered a basic synopsis of what REST is and what SOAP is and these were defined as architectures of an api.

The way the presenter defined it is that programs have languages and apis have architectures. Is this the proper definition of what an architecture is for an api?

I've looked around on google trying to compare the two terms programming language and architecture and haven't found a clear result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I recommend you to use Programmers or Web application Stask Exchange sites instead for such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement was almost definitely hand-wavey over-simplification, and was probably only correct within the context of the point he was trying to make.

Architecture is the design and documentation of the high-level functioning of programs and the interaction of those programs.

Programs are implemented in languages, APIs are implemented as programs.

APIs are a documentation of a particular interface to a program, and thus are part of an architecture.  APIs are implemented as programs, that themselves have architectures, that fit into a larger system architecture.

I would ignore his statement, it is not helpful to your mental model.  Understand what programs are, what languages are, and what architecture is.

REST and SOAP are not even peers.  REST is an architectural style, often implemented as HTTP verbs.  It is contrasted with RPC style web services, which are often implemented with SOAP.  SOAP is a protocol that sits on top of HTTP to implement RPC style web services, it is not an architecture, it is a protocol.  REST is not a protocol, it is an architectural element.  None of these are a full architecture in and of themselves.  SOAP/REST/HTTP/programs/languages all are components in an architecture.